# adodb, AutoExecute update field with field

Tags: database, field, updates, adodb, autoexec

i have table "users" like this

```
id  | firstname | lastname
==========================
1   | Ujang     | ahmad
2   | Jajat     | sudrajat
```

and have data :

```
$record = array('firstname'=>'some value', 'lastname'=>'some value');
$table  = "users";
```

and process update like this :

```
$exc= $conn->AutoExecute($table, $record, 'UPDATE', 'id = 1');
```

how do I update field firstname with the value of lastname use AutoExecute

so I get a result like this :

```
id  | firstname | lastname
==========================
1   | ahmad     | Ujang
2   | sudrajat  | Jajat
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand you, AutoExecute doesn't seem right for the job. If you need to do a one-time conversion of all records in your table I would just rename the columns.

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
CHANGE COLUMN `lastname` `firstname`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL AFTER `id`,
CHANGE COLUMN `firstname` `lastname`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL AFTER `firstname`;
```

Or in PHP/ADODB:

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `users`
  CHANGE COLUMN `lastname` `firstname`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL AFTER `id`,
  CHANGE COLUMN `firstname` `lastname`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL AFTER `firstname`;";
if (($result = $conn->Execute($sql)) === false)
  exit($sql.'<br />'.$conn->errorMsg());
```

If you need to target specific records you could use a temporary variable.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users
  SET firstname=(@temp:=firstname), firstname = lastname, lastname = @temp
  WHERE id=2";
if (($result = $conn->Execute($sql)) === false)
  exit($sql.'<br />'.$conn->errorMsg());
```

Cheers